# How to replace setTimeout() in Angular Material Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to use scroll after opening Material Autocomplete to scroll to a specific option using `_setScrollTop`. It is working fine when I use `setTimeout` but without it nothing is happening. Is there a way to avoid using timeout?

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-v8v7ft?file=src/app/app.component.ts) is a live example.

I am using `@ViewChild` to get autocomplete:

`@ViewChild('auto') testAuto: MatAutocomplete;`

And then calling `autoOpened()` function on Autocomplete `(opened)`

`<mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete" (opened)="autoOpened()">`

```
autoOpened() {

  // Not working
  this.testAuto._setScrollTop(30);

  // Working
  // setTimeout(() => {
  //   this.testAuto._setScrollTop(30);
  // })
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to avoid `setTimeout` in this case. Because autocomplete `panel` doesn't exist at that moment yet.
See [Angular Autocomplete sources](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/9a4a4cf2024d7f7ca409cdb9af0ce6a23863ddde/src/material/autocomplete/autocomplete.ts#L235):

```
  _setScrollTop(scrollTop: number): void {
    if (this.panel) {
      this.panel.nativeElement.scrollTop = scrollTop;
    }
  }
```